Parallel git branches that have the same changes but different commit hashes
I have a git repository that looks like this:
A1  -  B1  -  C1  -  D1  -  E1
           \
            \ C2  -  D2  -  F2

The file changes in C1 and C2 are identical. If I run git diff C1 C2 then I get an empty result. Likewise, the file changes in D1 and D2 are identical.
The commit messages of C1 and C2 are different, and the commit messages of D1 and D2 are also different.
The hashes of C1 and C2 are different. Likewise, the hashes of D1 and D2 are different.
The changes in E1 and F2 are completely different.
I would like to get a repository that looks like this:
A1  -  B1  -  C1  -  D1  -  E1
                         \
                          \ F2

I already tried git rebase and git rebase --onto and that just keeps the commits C2 and D2.
This is a fictional example. Here there are 2 commits that have the same changes. In reality there may be a few dozen or hundreds commits that have the same changes before the code diverges, and there is no simple way to determine how many without examining the entire history in detail.

What problem are you trying to solve here?

Maybe just indirectly related, but if you want to compare two commits by the Git tree they point to, i.e., ignore commit metadata like parent SHA, author, date etc., you can append ^{tree} to the revision; for example, git rev-parse C1^{tree} and git rev-parse C2^{tree}, and they would return the same hash.

@RomainValeri two contributors have cherry-picked the same range of commits in their own branch that was based on the same commit in main. The commits from contributor A are merged, and merging B's branch as-is would result in a history that is messier than needed.

As you probably know: git rebase resorts to an algorithm on the diff for each individual commit to detect if a commit is "already présent" on the other side.
There actually is a way to view this detection beforehand: look at the --cherry-* options in git help log :
# will draw a = in front of each commit which
# is also "on the other side"
git log --oneline --graph --boundary --cherry-mark E1...F2

# --cherry-pick will hide these commits altogether:
git log --oneline --graph --boundary --cherry-pick E1...F2

This may help you re-stitch more easily the histories of the two branches (technically you didn't ask a question, but it looks like you are trying to do this, am I correct?)

Thank you, I will try this and let you know the result.

This is normal. A git hash is determined not just by its "contents" (or "changes", as you put it) but by its parentage, meaning its place in the topology. Two different commits always have different hashes. Don't worry, be happy.
You could do the rebase you are describing by saying
git rebase --onto D1 D2 F2

but I really don't see what you think it would gain you. It would not magically delete C2 and D2, nor should it; commits in Git are never deleted, unless they are unreferenced (and even then, it takes a couple of weeks before they are cleaned up). And there would then be two F2 commits, so you would have doubled your (fake) trouble.

Rebasing makes new commits yet again, so you would end up with a different F2. So what is gained, really? Basically you're having worries you should not have, because you are not quite grasping what a commit is (or what Git is). History is history, just live with it.

You might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ to get a better sense of what Git is.
